# what is the purpose of 'values-v21' folder in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Please describe **Values-v21** folder in android and about the purpose and the use of this folder, why it is there in the project view, why only styles.xml is there in this folder.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 3):

The value-21 folder holds values specific to API level 21 and above. You can find more information at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources.